# Twitter Bootstrap 3: how to remove space used for carbon ads from page header?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3, and I notice that there's a carbon ad feature, which I'm not using, that is causing my page headers to wrap onto a 2nd line whenever the text occupies about 50% of the width (for large screens).

For example, the carbon ad in this page is in the big purple header block on the right side:

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Image the `Getting Started` text was much longer and there was no ad showing, it would wrap onto second line with big empty space on the right half, which looks bad.

First of all, what is this carbon ad stuff all about? If it's to easily enable people to make money from ads, I'm not interested.

Second of all, can this feature be disabled by modifying the css files somehow? I'd like to use the space for the carbon ads to allow my page headers to expand so more text fits on the first line. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found it... in docs.css file, change the right margin as follows:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .bs-docs-header h1, .bs-docs-header p {
    margin-right: 380px
  }
}
```

to

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .bs-docs-header h1, .bs-docs-header p {
    margin-right: 0px
  }
}
```